# How to cache whole page but without form's captcha? CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, captcha

I use captcha helper and I want to cache whole page. But how to cache all but without captcha's image from CodeIgniter's captcha helper?

I use `$this->output->cache(1);` in controller to cache whole page for one minute, but it caches Captcha too. How to handle this problem?

Comment: Caching is known to be a _hard_ problem. One approach that might help you is to separate your page into static and dynamic (or session specific) parts. Cache only the static parts.

Comment: Why do you cache the html? Do you have heavy database queries? If so, why not cache the database results and generate html every time with this data?